# Include a local JS client library in React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, blockly

I am trying to use google blockly in a react application. Based on the examples I have seen I need to include a JS library on the page using a script tag. I cannot seem to figure out how to do this in react even though it should be simple.

I could include a script from a CDN using a script tag no problem. But the JS library I have is local to my app. How can I include it?

```
<script src="relative/path/to/js"></script>
```

Root folder structure:
[image]

src folder:

[image]

Comment: Have you tried putting it in your HTML? This question seems to have no relation to React...

Comment: I am new to react, but as far as I can tell the app I am working with contains no HTML that is not embedded inside a react component.

Comment: Under the assumption that you're not using React Native and are in fact using ReactJS, that's not the case. The only way your bundled components can get rendered to a page is if the bundled script is included in a script element in the page. Could you list your folder structure, if you don't mind?

Comment: I updated to include the folder structure.

Comment: Check in the `views` folder. What's inside?

Comment: inside the views folder is 3 files, graphiql.pug, index.pug, layout.pug

Comment: Those `.pug` files are your views. You may read more about `pug` here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/pug https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html